# Jquery to target .this element not global

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm working with the folllowing code (not mine) and I'm trying to get the increment buttons to target only the form they relate to. However, when you have multiple forms like below, the increment box increases both (all) input boxes on the page.

How do I target only the form I'm using?

I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I can't figure it out! Please help!

Thanks a million in advance!

Elliott.

```
<form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</form>
<form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</form>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    // This button will increment the value
    $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    }); 
    // This button will decrement the value till 0
    $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            // Decrement one
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is not  related to your problem, but you should not give multiple elements the same id ('myform').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the field this way:

```
var $field = $(this).parent().find('input[name='+fieldName+']');
```

This will go up one element from the clicked element and then search your field from the available children.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // This button will increment the value
    $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        var $field = $(this).parent().find('input[name='+fieldName+']');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($field.val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
            $field.val(currentVal + 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $field.val(0);
        }
    }); 
    // This button will decrement the value till 0
    $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        var $field = $(this).parent().find('input[name='+fieldName+']');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($field.val());
        // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            // Decrement one
            $field.val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $field.val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</form>
<form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</form>
```

Comment: Consider using `.closest('form')` instead of `.parent()` to keep it working when the html structure inside the forms change

Answer (score 0):

To match only elements within the current form, replace all occurrences of:

```
$('input[name='+fieldName+']')
```

with:

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input[name='+fieldName+']')
```

Even better save it as a reference and use that:

```
var $field = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name='+fieldName+']');

// Now you can use...
$field.val();
```